# Why are these blocks not aligned on the same height?

Tags: html, css

**Aim**

To align the flags and tags on the same height

**Current**

[image]

**Expected**

[image]

**Code**

*html*

```
<div>
  <h1>
    {{ title }}
  </h1>
  <p>
    {{ body }}
  </p>
  <a href="#">
    <img id=dutchFlag (click)="setLang('nl')">
    <img id=ukFlag (click)="setLang('uk')">
  </a>
</div>
```

*css*

```
#buttons {
  float:left;
  padding:17px 40px 0 0;
}

#flag {
  float:right;
  padding:17px 40px 0 0;
}

#dutchFlag {
  background: url(../images/dutch-flag-50.jpg) no-repeat top right;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: block;
}

#ukFlag {
  background: url(../images/uk-flag-50.jpg) no-repeat top right;
  height: 48px;
  margin: 4px;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kgpzspst/).
You just needed to add a container to the flag images and use `float: right;`